# Flutter type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am trying to show a list of shoe sizes:**

```
Text( widget.shoe.size[i].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18), ),
```

**My shoe model is:**

```
class Shoe {final String name;
  final List<String> size;
  final String imageurl;

  Shoe(this.name, this.size, this.imageurl);
}


List<Shoe> shoes = [
  Shoe('Teebon M', ['38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
      'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/960/ke8uv0w0-0/shoe/i/g/f/cm4701-8-adidas-silvmt-cblack-ftwwht-original-imafuywffvmfxcgr.jpeg'),
  Shoe('Hyperon M,', ['38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
      'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/960/jseyoi80/shoe/n/v/u/ck9515-8-adidas-mysblu-ftwwht-cblack-original-imafdzrzkvud2eyc.jpeg'),
  Shoe('Glarus M', ['38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
      'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/960/kdrpksw0-0/shoe/f/a/k/cm4979-8-adidas-deeblu-silvmt-original-imafuhzgu4yyg6bp.jpeg'),
  Shoe('Pictor M', ['38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
      'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/960/ki96c280-0/shoe/n/r/x/ew2423-6-adidas-dovgry-gresix-stigrn-original-imafy38tfuytnxjk.jpeg'),
];
```

**But everytime i get this error:**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building Details(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _DetailsState#a0102):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result'
```

Comment: Your model is okay.. Maybe the problem is where you used your ```shoes``` and call the list. Can you add the code

Comment: Please update the code

Comment: The best way is to write test code, you can see the problem

Comment: You can just remove the .toString() since the widget.shoe.size[i] is a string already.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this was my first question i posted on stackoverflow and didn't expected to get answers so fast. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `widget.shoe.size[i]` does not contain the value you think it does.  The way you are creating the `Text` object looks fine.  Maybe try debugging to see what values `widget`, `widget.shoe`, etc have to see what your problem is.

Comment: Thankyou so much the answer your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the .toString() function, do it like this:

```
Text( '${widget.shoe.size[i]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18), ),
```

Comment: Thankyou so much the answer your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display the list of sizes you may concatenate all numbers in a single `String` and display it.

```dart
Text(widget.shoe.size.join(',') // comma separated numbers
```

Comment: Thankyou so much the answer your help is much appreciated